# Docker version documentation links

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-engine, docker-ce, docker-ee

Please help to understand with the docker version numbers.

Docker version 1.13.1, build 7f2769b/1.13.1 . ( https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/docker-engine/)
and
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea ( https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/)

Does it have any differences between these two versions on the latest updates. Can someone please help to understand which version is community version and enterprise version. It's a confusing.

Comment: From your links: `1.13.1 (2017-02-08)` - `19.03.5 2019-11-14`. So the first one is more than 2 years old. More over, on the first link if you look at the TOC on the left side, you will see it is in a section called "Superseded products and tools".

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/docker-engine/

> These release notes are for Docker Engine versions 1.13.1 and lower. For newer Docker releases, see Docker CE or Docker EE.

That page is not being updated anymore. It is only applicable for versions 1.13 and earlier.